# Choosing random action, Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 2 actions in a Flash file that I would like to test for conversion. One is opening a link in a tab/window, the other loading the content in a Colorbox iframe over the page.

How do I randomly choose one of the following actions?

I currently listen for a click on a button:

```
clickJoin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toJoin);
```

My two actions are:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/"), '_blank');
```

and

```
ExternalInterface.call('$.fn.colorbox({
    href: "http://www.google.com/",
    width:"80%",
    height:"80%",
    iframe:true,
    onLoad:function(){ $("#player").css({"visibility":"hidden"}); },
    onClosed:function(){ $("#player").css({"visibility":"visible"}); }})
');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To randomly choose between two options use `Math.random()` like this:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    // do action 1
} else {
    // do action 2
}
```